# Evaluating an infinite product of q-exponentials

Tags: special-functions, co.combinatorics

For  the $q$-exponential $$e_q(u) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{u^n}{[n]_q!}$$ with $[k]_q=\frac{1-q^k}{1-q}$ and $[n]_q! = [n]_q [n-1]_q \cdots [1]_q$, we don't have the property $e_q(u) e_q(v) = e_q (u+v)$.  I learned this the hard way when trying to compute the infinite product $$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty} e_q (x q^i)$$ where $x$ is an indeterminate.

- Does anyone see a way to get a closed form expression for this product?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you consider closed form here? A MacMahon type product? A generating function for plane partitions? Something else?...

Comment: Hopefully something else - but you're right that for a certain value of $x$ as a function of $q$ this will return the MacMahon generating function for plane partitions.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to write the generating function for plane partitions in terms of the q-exponential. Can you explain, or provide a reference please?  Or is it really easy and I'm just being stupid?  I guess I'm mainly asking out of personal interest, but it might be helpful.

Comment: Hey Ben - use the last comment in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-exponential

Comment: Ah, as I expected, I was being stupid.  :)

Comment: Btw, if you look at the answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89976/q-analog-of-the-matrix-exponential/89982#89982  there it is mentioned that upon using $q^2$ instead of $q$, you **do** have the nice $$\exp_q(u)\exp_q(v)=\exp_q(u+v)$$ formula...so perhaps this switch helps you simplify your sum too.